# Twitter template fails during sending direct message, but get rate limit request works

Tags: twitter, spring-social-twitter

Why direct message is not sent?

spring-social-twitter:1.1.2.RELEASE does not work with spring-web:5.0.6.RELEASE

Example of main class:

```
package com.test;
import org.springframework.social.twitter.api.ResourceFamily;
import org.springframework.social.twitter.api.impl.TwitterTemplate;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final TwitterTemplate template = new TwitterTemplate("TEST", "TEST","TEST", "TEST");
        template.userOperations().getRateLimitStatus(ResourceFamily.DIRECT_MESSAGES);
        System.out.println("Successfuly obtained rate limits");
        System.out.println("Sending DM");
        template.directMessageOperations().sendDirectMessage("user_id", "text");
     }
}
```

dependencies from gradle build file:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework:spring-web:5.0.6.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework.social:spring-social-twitter:1.1.2.RELEASE"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.5"
}
```

Result of execution:

```
Successfuly obtained rate limits
Sending DM
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/new.json": cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode; nested exception is java.net.HttpRetryException: cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:732)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:698)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:457)
    at org.springframework.social.twitter.api.impl.DirectMessageTemplate.sendDirectMessage(DirectMessageTemplate.java:77)
    at com.test.Main.main(Main.java:13)
Caused by: java.net.HttpRetryException: cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1692)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getRawStatusCode(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.hasError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:754)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:724)
    ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide a callback_url.
Go to your twitter app Settings page:

https://apps.twitter.com/

and fill in Callback Url input field. This will fix your I/O problem.

Comment: Calback URL is provided. It does not work with latest version of spring-web, but works with previous versions of spring-web.

Comment: @AndriyHospodarysko did you ever find a solution for this? I'm getting the same error when I try to send a tweet. The stacktrace is saying it's coming from spring-web-5.0.6.

Comment: @Elias I have reduced version of spring-web to 5.0.4 and it solved this problem.